# Formatting Mailing List archive

Tags: formatting, dialogue

I have archived a mailing list, with multiple writers/speakers, asking and answering questions on a variety of subjects.

I've been looking around for solutions, but none come close to what I'm looking for.

The archive is organized along subject lines. So let's say the first subject is "Sugar". What follows is then either a question or a statement on sugar, to which other people (all identified) then reply or question or complete. Sometimes, the original question is expended upon, before people move on.

Then, a second subject is raised, say, "Meat" ... and the same pattern of Q&A resumes and dialogue on that particular subjects starts again.

Any LaTex solution out there to format this whole mess into something visually clean, where each writer/speaker would be relatively identifiable, along their replies and questions?

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier to process the archive with a real programming language and generate the LaTeX rather than doing the whole thing with LaTeX.  If you wrote the preprocessing code in Lua you could integrate it with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Isn't thunderbird or a similar tol better for the job, since it is supposed to display mailing lists? You can sort by name, or date or subject. A pdf on the other hand is very static.

Comment: Easier then would perhaps be to define all authors in preamble and simply add each of these authors' code in front of their respective text. It'd be like a very long written dialogue between multiple participants.